# Python: Model.objects.all() - how to iterate through it using POST checkboxes

Tags: python, django, post, checkbox, changelist

I have been building a CSV export using Python/Django. While sending **all** items listed in the change list everything works like a charm.

Now, I've been trying to use Action dropdown and export **only those** items selected via the checkboxes, but I cannot make it work.

My current code, the one that works even with the Action dropdown yet exporting ALL items, regardless of what was checked:

```
def export_this_list(self, request, queryset):
    """Generates participants list in Excel sheet."""

    csv_elements = Enrolment.objects.all().order_by('-training__date')
    for elem in csv_elements:
```

When `csv_elements` is swapped with `request.POST.getlist` obviously nothing works.

```
def export_this_list(self, request, queryset):
    """Generates participants list in Excel sheet."""

    csv_elements = request.POST.getlist('_selected_action')
```

or

```
    csv_elements = []
    for o in request.POST.getlist('_selected_action'):
```

Question: 
what is the syntax to combine my Model with the POST action?

Comment: Can you show your template? What exactly is in `_selected_action`?

Comment: `_selected_action` is part of the default template shipped with Django - I need to use what I already have:

    <td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" value="44" type="checkbox"></td>

Comment: OK, you didn't say that this was in the admin. So, that is clearly sending a list of IDs. Where is the rest of that for loop? Are you querying the model anywhere?

Comment: Ouch - sorry: this is all for the Admin Panel. This is my current line to get all the items within a Model: csv_elements = Enrolment.objects.all().order_by('-training__date')

The rest of the loop doesn't really exist, cus I am not sure what the correct syntax should be and after several attempts, random attempts, all I get is bunch of errors, eg. _AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Enrolment'_

Comment: What I meant: when I swap the csv_elements line with this: 
_---csv_elements = []
    for o in request.POST.getlist('_selected_action'):---_, the rest of the loop doesn't really exist, I am stuck on selecting number of elements vs. all of them.

Comment: But as I said, that is returning *a list of IDs*. You obviously need to do a query to get the Enrolment objects for those IDs.

Comment: I am not sure how to answer your question, since my knowledge of P/D is next to non-existent. The model I have been using looks like sth that:

class Enrolment(models.Model):
    training = models.ForeignKey(Training, verbose_name=_('training'),
                                 related_name='enrolments')
    declarant = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                  related_name='enrolments',
                                  verbose_name=_('declarant'))
    invoice_data = JSONField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `csv_elements = Enrolment.objects.all()` you retrieve a set of Enrolment objects from the database that you subsequently iterate over.

But when you do `csv_elements = request.POST.getlist('_selected_action')` you have *a list of IDs*. You don't have Enrolment objects; they are still in the database, and you haven't done anything to get them. The IDs are the keys of the objects in the database, but as far as your code is concerned so far they're just numbers.

You need to actually go to the database to get those objects. Here's one way of doing that:

```
selected_ids = request.POST.getlist('_selected_action')
csv_elements = Enrolment.objects.filter(id__in=selected_ids)
```

Comment: Like I said, my knowledge of Python / Django is next to non-existent. When looking at your code everything seems to be so obvious, yet I wasted a lot of time not even getting close to your solution.

The code you gave me works like a charm, the exported list is exactly what it should be. Thank you very much!